# Linux Disk Write-Speed varies with dd command

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

Why there is so much of disk-write difference while checking with dd command `without bs` and `with bs`

## dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test.log count=100000000

```
100000000+0 records in
100000000+0 records out
51200000000 bytes (51 GB) copied, 289.564 s, 177 MB/s
```

## dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.log bs=1G count=50  oflag=dsync

```
50+0 records in
50+0 records out
53687091200 bytes (54 GB) copied, 150.427 s, 357 MB/s
```

## dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test2.log count=100000000

```
100000000+0 records in
100000000+0 records out
51200000000 bytes (51 GB) copied, 288.614 s, 177 MB/s
```

## dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test3.log bs=1G count=50  oflag=direct

```
50+0 records in
50+0 records out
53687091200 bytes (54 GB) copied, 109.774 s, 489 MB/s
```

I goggled through-out but did not get concrete example however there is good article [here](https://superuser.com/questions/580036/how-come-writing-varying-file-sizes-results-in-varying-speeds) which has few good caveates.

Comment: What's the filesystem on /tmp? Is it nearly full/empty? Spinning hard drive, USB flash, SSD? Did you clear the disk cache before each test? Absolutely no other programs could be reading or writing to the same drive, or any drive?

Comment: @Xen2050, sorry i was away,  Its Disk based allocated File System nearly having 1TB of Space out of which 700GB is Free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the `bs` parameter `dd` will use the standard block size of the device, very often 512 bytes. This means, that

- for every 512 bytes of payload you incur the overhead of a request.
- If the blocksize of 512 is not the optimal block size for your device (e.g. 4K sectors with 512 emulation or SSDs) you drive the devices far from their optimal working point.

Depending on your hardware, it might be possible to get even better numbers with a smaller `bs` as it will fit in the devices cache. E.g. for a RAID controller with 1GB cache, you might want to try a 10MB blocksize.

Comment: This is really nice anwer and substantial background on the actual problem.